# Can anyone identify these minifigures?

Tags: star-wars, minifigure-identification

I was searching Bricklink for info about the marked minifigures, but I can't find anything.

I want to know if these minifigures are fake or if these minifigs are in someone set that I can't find.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The figure holding the lightsaber is composed of the head and hair of [Anakin Skywalker from the Clone Wars](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sw0317) series:

[image]

the torso of [Luke Skywalker as a Jedi Knight](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sw0207/luke-skywalker-(jedi-knight)):

[image]

and [a pair of dark gray legs on medium gray hips](https://brickset.com/parts/4235863/mini-lowerpart-m-grey-dk-grey):

[image]

---

The clone figure has the torso of [a shock trooper from Ep 3.](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sw0091/clone-trooper-episode-3-red-markings-shock-trooper):

[image]

But I couldn't find the helmet.

Comment: The torso of the Anakin figure doesn't have the black hand of Luke though, so presumably the hand has been switched out too

Comment: WoW thank you for all this info!

Comment: @Gawey You're welcome!

Answer (score 19):

Zovits identified most items, the missing helmet is a [Stormtrooper Type 2 helmet from an AT-AT driver](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0262&name=AT-AT%20Driver%20(Bluish%20Grays,%20Black%20Head,%20Stormtrooper%20Type%202%20Helmet)&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%204/5/6%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), which is likely also where the legs from the Anakin/Luke mix figure as identified by Zovits come from.

[image]

As an added bonus: the torso of this AT-AT driver is used on the middle stormtrooper on the second row from the front, so you have the complete figure.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried searching for "clone", "imperial" and "republic", but "stromtrooper" did not occur to me :)

Comment: “Stromtrooper” would not have given you any results either *wink*

Comment: That's strange, I see that [it would have](https://brickset.com/minifigs?query=Stormtrooper).

Comment: @zovitssupportsGoFundMonica look carefully at the spelling [stromtrooper](https://brickset.com/minifigs?query=Stromtrooper) has no results

Comment: @KaranShishoo Oh, thanks, I see now :)

Answer (score 1):

The helmet is from an old AT-AT pilot. The set was from back in '09 I think.

Answer (score 1):

The snowtrooper on the left is not correct. Its torso goes with the AT-AT driver helmet in the question and, as already mentioned, the pants on your Luke-Anakin go with it as well.